# "Fait longtemps" or "faisait longtemps"

Tags: sens, temps-grammatical

I’d like to know the difference in meaning between these two sentences. How does the difference in tenses affect the meaning?

- > Cela fait longtemps que ma décision est prise.
- > Cela faisait longtemps que ma décision était prise.

Comment: First one: I have made up my mind a long time ago. Second one: I had made up my mind a long time ago.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two verbs *faire* and *être* have to belong to the same tense, meaning that either they're both *présent*, or they're both *passé*.

## The meaning

**Présent**

When you *know* that you've already made a choice.

Example :

> Cela fait longtemps que ma décision est prise : je vais aller à l'Université de Bordeaux, et non celle de Paris.

**Imparfait**

It refers to a past choice already revoked, which consequences has already happened. Back in that time, you *knew* that you had made a choice.

Example :

> En Février 1969, je savais que je ne le suivrai pas dans ses aventures en Amérique du Sud. Cela faisait longtemps que ma décision était prise, aussi douloureux était-ce.